# How do I regex just the title out?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Sample text:

```
1. Medium Size +CA $33.00
2. Small Size -CA $4.00
```

I would like the result to be just 'Medium Size' or 'Small Size' using `preg_match`

So the regex should detect the '-' or '+' sign and just give me the text output without the prices/currency

Tried

`(\S+)`

`(\S+\s+)`

Comment: Replace `[+-].*` with an empty string to remove everything starting at `+` or `-`.

Comment: Is `Extra-Large` a possible size? Then detecting the `-` is not what you really want.

Comment: @Sammitch Not sure if it was a good idea to make a code block from the list. Joshua please clarify if these are two sample text lines: `Medium Size +CA $33.00` and `Small Size -CA $4.00`. Or is it one multline string containing line numbers. For the first try e.g. [`^[^+-]*[^\s+-]`](https://regex101.com/r/Qd9XjL/2)

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should extract the title between the first field (`1.`) and last two fields separated by spaces (`+CA $33.00`):

`/^\S+ (.+) \S+ \S+$/`

To capture all the titles at once, use `preg_match_all()` and `m` flag:

```php
<?php

$txt = '1. Medium Size +CA $33.00
2. Small Size -CA $4.00
3. Extra-Large Size -CA $44.00';

preg_match_all('/^\S+ (.+) \S+ \S+$/m', $txt, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using php, you can make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far, and then get a match only for the part before the `+` or `-` sign

```
^\d+\.\h+\K[^\n+-]*[^\s+-]
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits followed by a `.`
- `\h+\K` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, and then forget what is matched so far using `\K`
- `[^\n+-]*` Match optional char other than `+` or `-` or a newline
- `[^\s+-]` Match at least a single non whitespace character other than `+` or `-`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9yBVLj/1)

If there should be a `+` or `-` sign present, you can assert it:

```
^\d+\.\h+\K[^\n+-]*[^\s+-](?=\h*[+-])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TOLBYW/1)

Or as an alternative a bit broader match starting with `\S+` and capturing as few as possible characters in group 1 until the first occurrence of 1+ spaces followed by either `+` or `-`

```
^\S+\h+(.+?)\h+[+-]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OgZiEd/1)